# Sumproduct sum with single cell works, but not with multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, sumproduct

The document that i have needs to calculate differnt entries and if these entries are found in the sales items, it should take them into the overall sum.

It seems to work if i pick one individual cell for each but not when i try to create ranges

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$D:$D=$S$1)*((Data!$E:$E=TEXT(H4,"0"))*(Data!$A:$A=$A$3)),Data!K:K)
```

`S1` = date
`H4` = productcode
`A3` = number
`Data!K:K` = the sales that have to be summed up

when i change the `H4` to `H4:k4`, i get the `#VALUE` error

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$D:$D=$S$1)*((Data!$E:$E=TEXT(H4:K4,"0"))*(Data!$A:$A=$A$3)),Data!K:K)
```

Comment: Have you tried entering the formula as an array formula? https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/02/25/array-formulas-functions-excel/ OR https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula

Comment: I now tried to use the OR function inside the SUMPRODUCT, which works nicely. It's not the most clean and short formula though, but will do

Comment: you probably need to change the `(Data!$E:$E=TEXT(H4:K4,"0")` part to `isnumber(search(Data!$E:$E,TEXT(H4:K4,"0")))`. But then you have to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

@Worempie

I would avoid array formula's, especially if you have a large dataset as they can be slow.

Are absolute referencing here on purpose?:

Data!$D:$D=**$S$1**

Data!$A:$A=**$A$3**

This will cause these cells not to move along when you move down your list of data (where ever your formula is placed).

Regarding your error, "when i change the H4 to H4:k4, i get the #VALUE error"

From the information you've provided I'm unclear what **Data!$E:$E=TEXT(H4:K4,"0")** is attempting to do, other than changing your product code to a text? The error is likely due to the fact that you can't reference a range within the text function. While my understanding of the SumProduct function is limited, I dont think you need to look at a range and reference a range, so if you remove your absolute referencing it should work for all your lines. In the case it doesn't the below will sum the sales values based on the date and matching product code.

=SUMPRODUCT(($C2=$J$2:$J$15)*($B2=$I$2:$I$15),$K$2:$K$15)

=SUMPRODUCT((([referencedproduct]=[ProductCodeEntries])*[ReferencedMonth]=[ProductDateEntries]),[SalesVals£])

Your data layout isn't clear, so I had to create something from "scratch". Hope this answers your question.